# "The system cannot find the file" error while using SED

Tags: windows, batch-file, sed, cmd

I am using `sed` to find total number of lines in a txt file.
I want to assign the output of sed to a variable.

I used the following code to do this:

```
for /f %%a in (`"sed15 -n $= TEST.TXT"') do set linenum=%%a
```

and I get this error message:

```
the system cannot find the file `"sed15 -n $= TEST.TXT"'
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Is this really MS-DOS (or Win9x)? Or cmd.exe under WinNT/2k/XP/Vista/... where command extensions are available?

Answer (score 1):

Needs to know how to interpret backquotes:

```
for /f "usebackq" %%a in (`sed15 -n $= TEST.TXT`) do (set linenum=%%a)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is looking for the file relative the the path you start the DOS command in. You can either give a full path for the file - c:\text.txt etc or start the command in the right directory.